# alternative to mediaRecorder on iOS

Tags: ios, html, video, stream

I want to send a video stream from an iOS device (version 11 and above) to a server (from a client using html5 on iOS).
For other browsers I get the stream from `navigator.getUserMedia`, and pass it to the server using mediaRecorder and a WebSocket:

```
this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(this._stream);
this.mediaRecorder.start(50);
this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    app.socket.emit("frameRequest", e.data);
}
```

however, MediaRecorder is not supported on iOS. Is there an alternative to sending the stream from iOS devices?

Answer (score 2):

There are a handful of polyfills that add MediaRecorder API support to browsers that don't support it natively, including iOS Safari.  My current favorite is [Opus Media Recorder](https://github.com/kbumsik/opus-media-recorder).

One problem I'm running into is that it only supports recording in Ogg or Wav formats, however iOS doesn't support playback of Ogg - only Wav, AAC, or MP3.  Unfortunately, Wav and AAC files are too big. So, I am taking the approach of recording in Wav and transcoding to MP3 in the browser using lamejs.

Comment: Anything that does video?

Comment: @Dois i was thinking this, if theoretically the video is loaded from the same domain  theoretically one can implement a video-recording mechanism from scratch by analyzing the bits of the raw file itself, perhaps with ffmpeg.js